# Correspondence Analysis on large table with many zeros

Tags: sparse-matrix, correspondence-analysis

Let's say I have a contingency table with many zero values. Can I even perform Correspondence Analysis? Will the results be valid? How to do the chi-square dependence test?

I feel that the CA approach is not suitable for this situation, but I do not have the technical background to support it. I will be grateful if someone can discuss the potential issues here. Thanks.